# How to remove and update raw datatype field from mongo Symfony

Tags: mongodb, symfony

Hi i have a Task document stored as follows:

```
 {
  "AssignTo": [
    {
      "$ref": "OrganisationUser",
      "$id": ObjectId("533665fcd841f8c00b000029"),
      "$db": "workStakMaster"
    }
  ],
  "BudgetedTime": "",
  "Client": {
    "$ref": "organisationClient",
    "$id": ObjectId("53327cebd841f8dc1000002a"),
    "$db": "workStakMaster"
  },
  "Project": {
    "$ref": "organisationProject",
    "$id": ObjectId("5332c9afd841f8fc1000002b"),
    "$db": "workStakMaster"
  },
  "RepeatType": "onetime",
  "TaskStatus": "NotStarted",
  "TimeSpentTillDate": "",
  "createdAt": ISODate("2014-04-03T10:57:31.0Z"),
  "description": "hi                                                ",
  "isActive": true,
  "isChargable": "No",
  "name": "A Task",
  "reminder": {
  "Daily": {
      "Time": ""
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": ISODate("2014-04-03T10:57:31.0Z")
}
```

I want to update "AssignTo" (which stores Many user as relations) Field only is it possible if yes please let me know exact way to do that.

Thanks Advance

Comment: Is it mapped to your entity? Not sure I understand what are you asking.

Comment: I got the solution for this myself.Thanks I am using MongoDB